# Clear Neo4j Embedded database

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

With a new version of Spring Data Neo4j I can't use Neo4jHelper.cleanDb(db);

So, what is the most effective way to completly clear Embedded Neo4j database in my application?

I have implemented my own util method for this purpose, but this method is slow:

```
public static void cleanDb(Neo4jTemplate template) {
    template.query("MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r", null);
}
```

How to properly clear/delete database ?

**UPDATED**

This is the similar question [How to reset / clear / delete neo4j database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310114/how-to-reset-neo4j-database) but I don't know how to programmatically shutdown Embedded Neo4j and how to start it after deleting.

I use Spring Data Neo4j and based on the user request I'd like to clear/delete existing database and recreate it with a new data. How to start up new embedded database after suggested invocation of shutdown method ?

**USE CASE:**

On the working application I have configured embedded database:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(environment.getProperty(NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY))
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "name,description")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true")
                .newGraphDatabase();
```

Also, I pre populate this database with 1000000 nodes. On the user request I need to clear this database and populate it with a new data. How to correctly and quick clear existing database ?

Can I call Neo4j database API for new node creation after `database.shutdown()` or do I need to initialize new database before it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset neo4j database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310114/how-to-reset-neo4j-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the other answer on the related question.  Inside of java, you can shut down an embedded database with the [`GraphDatabaseService#shutdown()`](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#shutdown%28%29) method.

From there, there are a pile of different ways you can delete the underlying directory, [see this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779519/delete-files-recursively-in-java).

So the general answer can still be the same:

1. Shutdown the database using the neo4j java API
2. Delete the database contents off of the disk

Comment: Thanks! One more question - if I need to delete/clear database several times on a working application - do I need to perform some additional steps in order to start using new embedded database right after deleting ?

Comment: No; embedded databases are tied to directories on disk.  Just create a new database, and it will auto-create whatever directories are necessary.

Comment: You must create a new database before you insert new data.  If you try to insert data after shutdown, it will fail.   Please mark this question completed and move on - if you have additional questions open new topics.