# How to reset a neo4j database if neo4j is used over java?

Tags: java, neo4j

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310114/how-to-reset-clear-delete-neo4j-database), one could use `rm -rf data/databases/graph.db` to reset database. However, after I ran this command in the folder `C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb`, while the folder databases is gone, when I run the java program, the nodes are still there; when I run neo4j via browser after restarting the server, the nodes are also there.

I loaded the data from csv files into neo4j with java driver.
This is the maven dependency for the driver:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

How should I reset the database?

Answer (score 2):

You might have a situation similar to the root cause of the issue in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286508/apoc-is-only-partially-installing-its-extension-in-neo4j-one-procedure/42357481#42357481).

There is a poorly documented difference between installing neo4j using an installer (which is most common) versus from a zip or tar file.

(A) When you install neo4j using an installer, the installer configures the neo4j server to look for the database folder in a path like the one you deleted.

(B) When you install neo4j from a zip or tar file, the neo4j server will look for the the database folder folder in the neo4j installation folder (e.g., `C:\path_to_neo4j_installation\data\databases\graph.db`).

Does (B) apply to you?

Comment: I uninstalled neo4j and re-installed it with zip. The command of `rm -rf ...` works for me now.